# How to make typeahead with handlerbars in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, typeahead

I am a beginner in yii2. I want to make search form in my project. So, i use typeahead with handlebars. But, it's not show the dropdown options. This is my code:

controller:

```
public function actionPrefetchlist()
    {
        $query = new Query;

        $query->select('nama')
                ->from('tb_penerima');
        $command = $query->createCommand();
        $data = $command->queryAll();
        $out = [];
        foreach ($data as $d){
            $out[] = ['value' => $d['nama']];
        }
        return Json::encode($out);
    }
```

view:

```
<?php
        echo '<label class="control-label">Select Repository</label>';
        $template = '<div><p>{{nama}}</p>';    //This is not working
        echo Typeahead::widget([
            'name' => 'twitter_oss', 
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
            'dataset' => [
                [
                    'prefetch' => Url::to(['paket/prefetchlist']),
                    'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                    'display' => 'value',
                    'templates' => [
                        'notFound' => '<div class="text-danger" style="padding:0 8px">Unable to find repositories for selected query.</div>',
                        'suggestion' => new JsExpression("Handlebars.compile('{$template}')")
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing in prefetch of typeahead handlerbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763443/missing-in-prefetch-of-typeahead-handlerbars)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
    echo '<label class="control-label">Select Repository</label>';
    echo Typeahead::widget([
        'name' => 'twitter_oss', 
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...'],
        'dataset' => [
            [
                'prefetch' => Url::to(['paket/prefetchlist']),
                'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                'display' => 'value',
                'templates' => [
                    'notFound' => '<div class="text-danger" style="padding:0 8px">Unable to find repositories for selected query.</div>',
                    'suggestion' => new JsExpression("Handlebars.compile('<div><p>{{value}}</p></div>')")
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
?>
```